# VBA: Importing sheets from another workbook containing macro

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I created a simple macro in Excel to open up another workbook and copy the sheets into the workbook. This worked great for ordinary xls files but when I tried using it on a .xltm file containing a macro I got an out of bounds error because of the macro it contained.

Is there any possible way in Excel vba to open up a workbook and copy and sheet in it containing a macro?

My code

```
Dim directory As String, fileName As String, sheet As Worksheet, total As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
directory = "c:\"
fileName = Dir(directory & "book1.xls")
Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)
For Each sheet In Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets
   total = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
   Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets(sheet.Name).Copy after:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(total)

Next sheet
```

Thanks guys,

Comment: just to point out that inside the `For Each sheet` loop you can simply use `sheet` instead of `Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets(sheet.Name)`

Answer (score 0):

Could it have something to do with your

```
fileName = Dir(directory & "book1.xls")
```

when you are using an xlsm file instead?

Comment: Maybe you have to save the file as a .xlsm before copying the sheets in.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the reply. I did change the file name to the file in question which containts a button and a macro where it adds a page once clicked. The debugger stopped on the line of the imported sheet where it is trying to add a new sheet.